# Creating BIG images

Tags: c++, c, image, bitmap

First of all, hello there !

then, a little bit of context :

I am actually working on a "Maze Generator". I can, for now, generate mazes with 18500 width and 18500 height (which makes me kind of happy !!).

So, no problem with the generation.

Then, of course, I wanted to write them into a .jpeg / .bmp or else files.

So, for a 18k5*18k5 maze, I need a 37k*37k image.

I first tried with .jpeg. It worked, but the output files were 1.2 GigaBytes big. Those take ages too open ... but I can open them.

So I tried to use the BMP format instead because it allows to encode pixels on 1 bit each. The output files are now reaaaally smaller .... but I cant open them ... I am telled that the files are "corrupted or too big".

I dont think they are corrupted because it worked with a 10k*10k maze (20k*20k image) and it failed to open, with the same code, a 13k*13k maze (26k*26k image).

So here is the code (I am using EasyBMP lib) :

```
int             main()
{
  HandyMaze         labz(MAZE_SIDE, MAZE_SIDE); // Maze generator
  Labz*             l;                         // Maze iteself
  BMP               img;

  if (labz.Generate() == false)
    {
      std::cout << "Derp" << std::endl;
      return (1);
    }
  l = labz.GetFormatedLab();
  if (l == 0)
    {
      std::cout << "Dorp" << std::endl;
      return (1);
    }
  std::cout << "Generated" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Creating Image ..." << std::endl;
  img.SetSize(l->w, l->h);
  if (img.SetBitDepth(1) == false)
  {
    std::cout << "Failed to change Depth" << std::endl;
    return (1);
  }
  std::cout << "Filling Image ..." << std::endl;
  std::cout << l->w << " " << l->h << std::endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < l->w; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < l->h; ++j)
      {
        if (l->lab[j][i] == WALL)
        {
        img(j, i)->Red = 0;
        img(j, i)->Green = 0;
        img(j, i)->Blue = 0;
        img(j, i)->Alpha = 0;
        }
        else
        {
        img(j, i)->Red = 255;
        img(j, i)->Green = 255;
        img(j, i)->Blue = 255;
        img(j, i)->Alpha = 0;
        }
      }
  std::cout << "Saving Image ..." << std::endl;
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << "Laby-" << MAZE_SIDE << ".bmp";
  img.WriteToFile(ss.str().c_str());
  return (0);
}
```

As you can see, the drawing code is really simple but still ... Am I missing something or am I trying to do something I cant do xD?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

PS : First time posting here, I tried to be as clear as possible but tell me if I did something the wrong way.

Rel4X

Comment: I believe that BMP files must have a header (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#File_structure)

Comment: Hi brain. Yes and it seems my sizes are well under the maximum size : The header says 4 bytes for height and width and total size. 4 bytes signed is something like 2000000000 pixels. I have 1369000000 pixels.

Comment: Try settings the alpha channel to 255.

Comment: Hmm nope it did not work either with alpha = 255 ... Still stuck with the same problem.

Comment: create a small sample image, make it available here and I'll tell you what's wrong with it.

Comment: The small images work, but I'll give you one very soon (cant now). Many thanks for the help !

Comment: Here is a 100*100 maze (201*201 pixels image) : http://sendbox.fr/pro/8ihfygnlj3pk/Laby-100.bmp.html

Comment: Little up because I am still stuck with this :x

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about the problem with using easybmp lib, but alternatively you can try to use libpng.

You can check the below code (using libpng) to write a bigger dimension image file also the libpng produces much compressed file. You can modifiy the code to your needs. Hope it helps.

```
/***********************************************************
This is a modification of the original code taken from 
http://www.lemoda.net/c/write-png/
***********************************************************/

#include "png.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

/* A coloured pixel. */

typedef struct {
    char color;
} pixel_t;

/* A picture. */

typedef struct  {
    pixel_t *pixels;
    size_t width;
    size_t height;
} bitmap_t;

/* Given "bitmap", this returns the pixel of bitmap at the point 
   ("x", "y"). */

static pixel_t * pixel_at (bitmap_t * bitmap, int x, int y)
{
    return bitmap->pixels + bitmap->width * y + x;
}

/* Write "bitmap" to a PNG file specified by "path"; returns 0 on
   success, non-zero on error. */

static int save_png_to_file (bitmap_t *bitmap, const char *path)
{
    FILE * fp;
    png_structp png_ptr = NULL;
    png_infop info_ptr = NULL;
    size_t x, y;
    png_byte ** row_pointers = NULL;
    png_byte *row = NULL;
    /* "status" contains the return value of this function. At first
       it is set to a value which means 'failure'. When the routine
       has finished its work, it is set to a value which means
       'success'. */
    int status = -1;
    /* The following number is set by trial and error only. I cannot
       see where it it is documented in the libpng manual.
    */
    int pixel_size = 1;
    int depth = 8;

    fp = fopen (path, "wb");
    if (! fp) {
        goto fopen_failed;
    }

    png_ptr = png_create_write_struct (PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (png_ptr == NULL) {
        goto png_create_write_struct_failed;
    }

    info_ptr = png_create_info_struct (png_ptr);
    if (info_ptr == NULL) {
        goto png_create_info_struct_failed;
    }

    /* Set up error handling. */

    if (setjmp (png_jmpbuf (png_ptr))) {
        goto png_failure;
    }

    /* Set image attributes. */

    png_set_IHDR (png_ptr,
                  info_ptr,
                  bitmap->width,
                  bitmap->height,
                  depth,
                  PNG_COLOR_TYPE_GRAY,
                  PNG_INTERLACE_NONE,
                  PNG_COMPRESSION_TYPE_DEFAULT,
                  PNG_FILTER_TYPE_DEFAULT);

    /* Initialize rows of PNG. */
    printf("Filling image...\n");
    png_init_io (png_ptr, fp);
    png_write_info(png_ptr, info_ptr);

    row_pointers = png_malloc (png_ptr, sizeof (pixel_t *));
    row = png_malloc (png_ptr, sizeof (pixel_t) * bitmap->width * pixel_size);
    for (y = 0; y < bitmap->height; ++y) {
        for (x = 0; x < bitmap->width; ++x) {
            pixel_t * pixel = pixel_at (bitmap, x, y);
            row[x-1] = pixel->color;
        }
        png_write_row(png_ptr, row);
    }
    png_free (png_ptr, row_pointers);

    /* Write the image data to "fp". */
    printf("Writing image...\n");
    png_write_end(png_ptr, info_ptr);

    /* The routine has successfully written the file, so we set
       "status" to a value which indicates success. */

    status = 0;
    /*
    for (y = 0; y < bitmap->height; y++) {
        png_free (png_ptr, row_pointers[y]);
    }
    png_free (png_ptr, row_pointers);
    */
 png_failure:
 png_create_info_struct_failed:
    png_destroy_write_struct (&png_ptr, &info_ptr);
 png_create_write_struct_failed:
    fclose (fp);
 fopen_failed:
    return status;
}

/* Given "value" and "max", the maximum value which we expect "value"
   to take, this returns an integer between 0 and 255 proportional to
   "value" divided by "max". */

static int pix (int value, int max)
{
    if (value < 0)
        return 0;
    return (int) (256.0 *((double) (value)/(double) max));
}

int main ()
{
    bitmap_t fruit;
    int x;
    int y;

    /* Create an image. */

    fruit.width = 37000;
    fruit.height = 37000;

    fruit.pixels = calloc (sizeof (pixel_t), fruit.width * fruit.height);
    printf("creating image...\n");
    for (y = 0; y < fruit.height; y++) {
        for (x = 0; x < fruit.width; x++) {
            pixel_t * pixel = pixel_at (& fruit, x, y);
            if((x+y)%2)
            {
                pixel->color = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                pixel->color = 255;
            }
        }
    }

    /* Write the image to a file 'fruit.png'. */

    save_png_to_file (& fruit, "fruit.png");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll give it a try ! ... Still stuck with this, I am having a very bad time xD //